# In perl, why splitting a string on pattern gives a null character at some splitting points

Tags: regex, perl, split

Suppose I have a string as following:

```
my $line="(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)*(1+l_tax))";
```

I want to split this string whenever it gets a non-word character and I also want to remember the character. Here goes my code for that:

```
my @split_on_non_word=split /(\W)/,$line;
print scalar @split_on_non_word, "\n";
print "split:$_\n" for @split_on_non_word;
```

**Here is my output:**

```
20
split:
split:(
split:l_extendedprice
split:*
split:
split:(
split:1
split:-
split:l_discount
split:)
split:
split:*
split:
split:(
split:1
split:+
split:l_tax
split:)
split:
split:)
```

The problem is, I am getting null characters inside my array at patterns e.g. (, *. I am sensing that may be it has something to do with metacharacters. But, it does not insert any null characters when splitting on "+" which is also a metacharacter. Any help on this regard is very much appreciated.

Off course, there are ways to post process the array and get rid of the null characters, which is my work-around for now. But, I am just looking for a better solution.

**Expected output:**

```
15
split:(
split:l_extendedprice
split:*
split:(
split:1
split:-
split:l_discount
split:)
split:*
split:(
split:1
split:+
split:l_tax
split:)
split:)
```

Comment: There is no `null` in Perl. The rough equivalent is `undef`, which is an undefined value. Your empty lines are simply _the empty string_.

Comment: You can use the `\b` escape sequence for a word boundary, but that will yield 11 results, because things with `()` are treated as one word, like `))` and `)*(`. Those could be split afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the word boundary `\b` with a check for `\W`, in which case you split on the empty string, which just turns a string into a list of characters.

```
my $line="(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)*(1+l_tax))";

my @split_on_non_word = map { /\W/ ? split '', $_ : $_ } split /\b/,$line;
print scalar @split_on_non_word, "\n";
print "split:$_\n" for @split_on_non_word;
```

Output:

```
15
split:(
split:l_extendedprice
split:*
split:(
split:1
split:-
split:l_discount
split:)
split:*
split:(
split:1
split:+
split:l_tax
split:)
split:)
```

Comment: It looks like someone just came by and downvoted both of our answers. I wouldn't expect any explanation.

Answer (score 7):

`split()` may not be the best way for desired outcome, you can use regex,

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $line="(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)*(1+l_tax))";
my @split_on_non_word = $line =~ /(\w+|\W)/g;

print Dumper \@split_on_non_word;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      '(',
      'l_extendedprice',
      '*',
      '(',
      '1',
      '-',
      'l_discount',
      ')',
      '*',
      '(',
      '1',
      '+',
      'l_tax',
      ')',
      ')'
    ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

Capturing in a split pattern only rarely works exactly as needed for some task.  When it doesn't, you either have to post-process the results, use match instead of split, or try to come up with a non-capturing split pattern that does what you want.  Other answers take one of the first two approaches.  For the third, you want to split wherever there is a non-word character to either side, which is easy:

```
split /(?<=\W)|(?=\W)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared every `\W` character to be a field separator. The first character of the string is `(`. That means it must separate an empty string from what follows.

Then you have `*(`: A sequence of two separators. That means, there must be an empty field between them.

As for `1+l_tax`, clearly, there are non-empty strings on either side of the separator, `+`.

To me, it seems simplest just to filter out the empty fields:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML::XS;

my $line = "(l_extendedprice*(1-l_discount)*(1+l_tax))";

my $tokens = [ grep length, (split /(\W)/, $line) ];

print scalar @$tokens, "\n";

print Dump $tokens;
```

Output:

```
15
---
- (
- l_extendedprice
- '*'
- (
- '1'
- '-'
- l_discount
- )
- '*'
- (
- '1'
- +
- l_tax
- )
- )
```

Comment: Why did you load YAML?

Comment: Because I like its `Dump` better than other dumps, and I didn't like the way the OP was printing the results.